# Are derivatives defined on functions or variables?

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, partial-derivative

My question is, is differentiation done on functions or on variables/values?

For example take $z=f(x,y)$, in this case we can 'fix' one of the variables to the value $y_0$, the question then becomes, is the derivative of $z_0=f_y(x,y)$ defined here? $y$ is now constant, however if our derivative is defined on $f$ the partial derivative should exist.

Does it make sense to talk about the rate that $f(x,y_0)$ is changing? can we for example write $\frac{dz_0}{dx}$? or $\frac{d(f(x,y0))}{dx}$? to talk about the rate the *value* $f(x,y_0)$ changes? Or can we only discuss the *function*'s partial derivatives $f_x'(x,y_0)$ and $f_y'(x,y_0)$?

Another thing is that if we apply $f$ to two arguments who depend on each other, we provide the total derivative, which is actually different depending on their relation, if the function is defined independently how can this be the total derivative of a function?

If we take $\frac{df(x^2)}{dx}$, it seems we take the 'derivative' of the value $f(x^2)$ , but perhaps this notation can be seen as the 'derivative of the function whose value is $f(x^2)$', but seems a bit strange.

Do we take the derivative of a 'value' or variable or is it better to keep Euler 'notation'.

Comment: We take the derivative of a function with respect to a variable, keeping other variables fixed; that is, the derivative as an operation takes *three* inputs: a function, a variable, and the data of which variables are being kept fixed (which is rarely made explicit in the notation).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan the function is a function though, it has no 'variables', the variables are in he expressions that are used to express he value of the function at a point in the domain., do you mean, the function, and which input?

Comment: A variable as "$x$" can be also considered as a function (even with more than this one variable). The derivate with respect to $x$ is $1$ whereas the derivate with respect to $y$ is $0$.

Comment: @Peter I guess so, I think I should specify, 'the value of a function', $x$ as an expression can be thought of as the value of a linear function's value at $x$, I mean more like the value of a function like $y$ or $f(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tl; dr: Functions.

---

In mathematics, a function is an abstraction of a *deterministic relationship*, often (but not necessarily) between two numerical quantities. Only once a relationship is fixed does a "rate of change" make sense. But in any case, the *relationship* governs the rate of change, not the quantities.

If you'll excuse a mildly provocative comment, the conceptual problem here stems from Leibniz notation, which hides functional relationships. Leibniz notation is incredibly useful when one computes, but when one is trying to understand calculus theoretically Leibniz notation (in my experience) loses out to Newtonian notation.

Let's consider the examples in question:

> For example take $z=f(x,y)$, in this case we can 'fix' one of the variables to the value $y_0$, the question then becomes, is the derivative of $z_0=f_y(x,y)$ defined here? $y$ is now constant, however if our derivative is defined on $f$ the partial derivative should exist.

From a Newtonian perspective, we've defined a *new function* of one variable, say $g(x) = f(x, y_{0})$. The "derivative with respect to $y$" makes no sense.

> Does it make sense to talk about the rate that $f(x,y_0)$ is changing? can we for example write $\frac{dz_0}{dx}$? or $\frac{d(f(x,y0))}{dx}$? to talk about the rate the *value* $f(x,y_0)$ changes? Or can we only discuss the *function*'s partial derivatives $f_x'(x,y_0)$ and $f_y'(x,y_0)$?

Here, in the preceding notation, it's reasonable to interpret "the rate of change" as $g'$. That's a "total derivative" of $g$. It can also be interpreted as a partial derivative of $f$ with respect to its first variable, namely $D_{1}f(x, y_{0})$ in the notation of Spivak's *Calculus on Manifolds*.

> Another thing is that if we apply $f$ to two arguments who depend on each other, we provide the total derivative, which is actually different depending on their relation, if the function is defined independently how can this be the total derivative of a function?

This is a reasonable question, but exemplifies why Leibniz notation is a source of confusion. Standard quasi-paradoxes with the multivariable chain rule are often set up in this framework. Writing $w = w(x, y, z) = w(x, y, z(x, y)) = w(x, y)$, for example, is asking for trouble on more levels than I care to count. These tangles can be reconciled by carefully defining functions, using different letters for different deterministic relationships.

> If we take $\frac{df(x^2)}{dx}$, it seems we take the 'derivative' of the value $f(x^2)$ , but perhaps this notation can be seen as the 'derivative of the function whose value is $f(x^2)$', but seems a bit strange.

From a Newtonian perspective, we're introducing $g(x) = f(x^{2})$, so $g'(x) = 2xf'(x)$ is "the rate of change" by the chain rule. One might, I suppose, expect instead that "the rate of change" is $f'(x^{2})$, the derivative of $f$ evaluated at $x^{2}$, but I think that is not how most people would read $\frac{df(x^{2})}{dx}$.

Incidentally, Leibniz notation makes writing $f'(x^{2})$ inconvenient at best. As a result, at least some calculus students develop a tacit misconception that evaluation and differentiation commute. This bold assertion is based on experiences teaching the multivariable chain rule.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response, I have one question which just came to me now, if we have $\frac{df(x)}{dx}$ is this the derivative of $f$, or the derivative of $f(x)$ the value in the latter case it seems more like this is the value of $f'$ at $x$, but is it actually the function $f'$, so that we could have $\frac{df(x)}{dx}(z)$?

Comment: That, in my view, is an excellent illustration of the ambiguity of Leibniz notation. I'd read it as $f'(x)$, the value of the derivative at $x$, but you might get different answers from others, especially in other fields and disciplines.